# Using a variable to declare multiple structs in C

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, struct

I am wondering if there is a way that I can declare x amount of structs using the i variable from a for loop:

```
int playersAmount, i;

printf("How many players are there?");
scanf("%i", &playersAmount);

for (i = 1; i <= playersAmount; i++) {
    struct players //player(i);
}
```

Let's say I would like there to be 5 players. I would like the for loop to create struct players player1, struct players player2, struct players player 3, etc... based on the i variable.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I have already defined the struct, but did not include that in the given body of code. :)

Comment: In C99 or later, outside the loop (not inside it), you can write `struct players player[i];`.  Inside the loop, you throw away the array on each iteration, which isn't what you want.  These are known as variable length arrays — VLAs — and are not supported by all compilers (MS Visual Studio has long been a hold-out, though it might now support it; you can check as well as I can).

Comment: you can declare an array of pointers and allocate each one (say with malloc) and save the pointers to each struct in the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of struct like

```
struct players myplayers[5];
```

and then using the for loop you can assign values like

```
int main()
{
int a;
 for(a = 0; a < 5; a++)
 {
        myplayers[a].score = 1;
 }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least show the declaration of the array.  You might or might not be comfortable describing a VLA — variable length array.  (You might or might not be cognizant of their existence.)